# Подключение по RDP к виртуальной машине

Tags: windows, vmware, rdp

Есть стационарный компьютер домашней сети, на котором развернута виртуальная машина VMWare с win 10 pro. Компьютер подключён по Ethernet к роутеру. Необходимо подключаться по RDP к виртуальной машине с ноутбука (win 8.1), который подключен к роутеру по wifi. Нашёл информацию как настроить RDP на виртуальной машине, в итоге с компьютера могу к "виртуалке" по RDP подключаться, а  с ноутбука не получается. Посоветуйте, что необходимо сделать, т.к. в этом деле не разбираюсь. Посмотрел тут по похожим вопросам, видимо, нужно делать проброс портов, или должно и так работать?

Comment: В настройках VM в качестве сетевого адаптера должен быть выбран NAT. В нём делаете проброс порта 3389 (локалка ведь?) на любой свободный порт. Фактически, всё. Увы, нет готовой виртуалки с Win, только Linux'овские, так бы показал со скриншотами

Comment: Скажите, а проброс делается на самой "виртуалке" или где то в роутере?

Comment: Сейчас попробую собрать ответ

Comment: @ViktorTomilov зачем же NAT? Пусть напрямую на том же интерфейсе, что вай-фай. И пусть виртуальная винда получает dhcp от роутера

Comment: @DmitryKozlov у меня реплика всегда тормозила, поэтому не люблю подобный подход

Comment: Нахрена `нат`, если можно `сетевой мост`? Тогда виртуалка будет видна как ещё один комп в локалке и порты будут открыты все, которые там открыты в принципе. Никакого порт форвардинга делать не надо.

Comment: @donRumata повторюсь: у меня этот вариант всегда тормозил

Comment: @ViktorTomilov, у меня сетевой мост последние лет 8, а то и 10 - единственная конфигурация сети и для линуксовых и для виндовых тачек, которые я создаю\удаляю для тестов. И win7-64 и win10-64 отлично пашут именно через rdp. Цепляться через окно виртуалки - неудобно - разрешение маленькое, а ставить виртуальные дрова не позволяют задачи - виртуалка идёт как эталонный образ для bare metal. Всё отлично пашет - даже Автокад запускается нормально, чисто чтобы проверить видит сетевую лицензию или нет. Правда я пользуюсь ubuntu на хосте и virtualbox. Но и в редких случаях на хосте с виндой тоже ок.

Comment: @donRumata Надо перепроверить при случае, я тоже win года 4 не пользовал в таком виде, сейчас и нужда создавать удаленку для виртуалки отпала.

Answer (score 0):

(У меня нет настроенной VM Windows под рукой, но скриншоты настройки сети будут идентичны для Linux и Windows, так что, ежели где будет видно Ubuntu - не стоит пугаться)

Как я понимаю, существует несколько способов организации удаленного доступа (RDP) к виртуальной машине с локальных компьютеров. Рассмотрим, на мой взгляд, наиболее правильный:

1. Идём в настройки виртуальной машины:
   [image: Настройки VM]
   убеждаемся, что включен NAT
2. Определяем (ipconfig на виртуалке) IP адрес и шлюз виртуальной машины.
   У меня это 192.168.48.28 и 192.168.48.2
3. Теперь идём в меню Edit/Virtual Network Editor, подтверждаем административное вмешательство, получаем вот такое окно:

[image: NAT]

Жмём кнопку NAT Settings, попадаем сюда:

[image: добавление настройки NAT]

Жмём Add, для хоста выбираем любой свободный порт (обычно рекомендуют старше 40000, но у меня точно свободны порты 999*, поэтому я выбираю 9999), тип - TCP, вводим IP-адрес виртуальной машины 192.168.48.28, и RDP-порт 3389:

[image: проброс портов]

Сохраняем всё, сервис NAT виртуалки должен перезагрузиться. Теперь мы имеем порт для доступа к нашей виртуальной машине из локальной сети. Не забываем разрешить доступ к порту 9999 на хосте.

Ещё один путь - использовать прямое подключение (реплику). Но мне он никогда не нравился, поскольку всегда был медленным и не обладал той же гибкостью.